# Yii2 Dependency Injection

Tags: yii2, dependency-injection

Как работать с Dependency Injection в Yii2 ? К примеру в том же Phalcon все просто и понятно

```
// Create a DI
$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Setup the view component
$di->set(
    "view",
    function () {
        $view = new View();

        $view->setViewsDir("../app/views/");

        return $view;
    }
);

$application = new Application($di);
$response = $application->handle();
$response->send();
```

Если сделать тоже самое в Yii2

```
$di = new yii\di\Container;

$di->set('db', [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);

$application = new yii\web\Application($di);
$application->run();
```

Получим ошибку

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type yii\di\Container as array

Comment: Почему вы в yii\web\Application() пытаетесь запихнуть экземпляр контейнера, когда туда передается массив настроек приложения?

Comment: Да, посмотрел исходники, так и есть. Я хотел избавиться от конфигурации через массив в первую очередь, поэтому и решил использовать di(не только поэтому). Тогда какой смысл в этом di в Yii2, если все равно придется конфигурировать через массивы все ? В Phalcon задается конфиурация в di, а в Yii все как обычно, все через то самое место :(

Answer (score 2):

> а в Yii все как обычно, все через то самое место :(

Как обычно, "через одно место" только у тех, кто не умеет [читать документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html).

Конфигурировать DI можно максимально возможными способами:

```
Yii::$container->set('app\models\UserFinderInterface', [
    'class' => 'app\models\UserFinder',
]);

Yii::$container->set('userLister', 'app\models\UserLister');

Yii::$container->set('db', function ($container, $params, $config) {
    return new \yii\db\Connection($config);
});
```

А с версии 2.0.11 более удобным, на мой взляд, способом - через конфигурацию приложения:

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'extensions' => require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php'),
    'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            'yii\widgets\LinkPager' => ['maxButtonCount' => 5]
        ],
        'singletons' => [
            // Dependency Injection Container singletons configuration
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Документацию я читал. Интересовала именно возможность конфигурации как в Phalcon, чтобы не использовать этот самый "более удобный" способ, т.е. не пихать все и вся в один массив.

Comment: В первом примере кода и есть "как в Phalcon"

Comment: Не увидел в нем запуска самого приложения.

Comment: Если вы внимательно почитаете документацию и посмотрите на index.php, то всё получится.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее удобным на мой взгляд, является способ конфигурации DI через параметры конструктора - 
вы указываете параметры с тайп-хинтингом, например так:

```
public function __construct(SomeComponent $component, 
    ISomeInterface $publicInterface, $config = []) 
{
}
```

В таком случае, если вы будете создавать экземпляр класс с этим конструктором не напрямую через оператор new а через **Yii::createObject()**, то DI-контейнер подставит сюда необходимые экземпляры указанных классов и интерфейсов.
В случае интерфейсов или абстрактных классов где-нибудь раньше Вы должны указать соответствие, как-то так:

```
Yii::$container->set('ISomeInterface', 'ConcreteImplementaionClass');
```

Этим Вы дадите понять контейнеру, что в случае зависимости от интерфейса **ISomeInterface**, он должен "поднимать" экземпляр класса ** ConcreteImplementaionClass**.

Разумеется, этот подход работает рекурсивно - у зависимостей могут быть свои зависимости.

Вполне вероятно, что кто-то скажет что это не совсем гибко. Меня вполне устраивает и, более того, позволяет в большинстве случаев оставить код чистым от лишних "преднастроек".